# Rails/ActiveRecord: Why does count result in a syntax error when called on my ActiveRecord:Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been trying to optimize a query. I have a model named `Issue` and a model named `Labels` they have a many to many relationship.

To get a list of `issues` that has `labels` with names that match every item in a given array, I'm using:

```
    Issue.select('issues.id, count(labels.id) as matching_label_count')
      .joins(:labels)
      .where(labels: { name: [*labels] })
      .having("matching_label_count = #{labels.size}")
      .group('issues.id')
```

Using pry, I see that the query returns an `Issue::ActiveRecord_Relation` as expected and that it responds to `ActiveRecord::Calculations` methods. However, when I call `count` on the result I get a syntax error:

```
    pry(main)> Issue.select('issues.id, count(labels.id) as
    matching_label_count').includes(:labels).where(labels: { name: labels
    }).having("matching_label_count = #{labels.size}").group('issues.id').count
    (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT issues.id, count(labels.id) as
    matching_label_count) AS
    count_issues_id_count_labels_id_as_matching_label_count, issues.id,
    count(labels.id) as matching_label_count, issues.id AS issues_id FROM "issues"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."issue_id" = "issues"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "labels" ON "labels"."id" = "tags"."label_id" WHERE "labels"."name" IN (?, ?)
    GROUP BY issues.id HAVING (matching_label_count = 2) ORDER BY
    "issues"."created_at" DESC  [["name", "bug"], ["name", "enhancement"]]

    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "as": syntax error:
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT issues.id, count(labels.id) as matching_label_count) AS
    count_issues_id_count_labels_id_as_matching_label_count, issues.id,
    count(labels.id) as matching_label_count, issues.id AS issues_id FROM "issues"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."issue_id" = "issues"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "labels" ON "labels"."id" = "tags"."label_id" WHERE "labels"."name" IN (?, ?)
    GROUP BY issues.id HAVING (matching_label_count = 2) ORDER BY
    "issues"."created_at" DESC from /Users/Arnould/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1
    .3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize' Caused by
    SQLite3::SQLException: near "as": syntax error from /Users/Arnould/.rvm/gems/ruby-
    2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

It does however work fine with `length`. `size` returns a hash with a count (`label_name_count`) as the value and the issue id as the key.

I already have half a dozen tests calling `count` on the result I want to know why it doesn't work before I consider changing them.

What is causing `#count` to fail and how can I fix it my query to ensure it works?

Answer (score 4):

You have hard wired `count(labels.id) as matching_label_count` within the select projection of your query. When you use the `count` method, ActiveRecord will wrap all of your select fields inside a `COUNT` of its own leading to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT issues.id, count(labels.id) as matching_label_count) AS
    count_issues_id_count_labels_id_as_matching_label_count
```

That alias/`as` within the count is invalid SQL and that is why sqlite3 reports the error.

If you rely on `length` or `size`, the query is unaltered, i.e. selects not wrapped inside a `count` and executed first. Only after the records are retrieved and the models are initialised are the instances counted. That will work as such but is highly inefficient if you are only interested in the count. If you need the instances elsewhere as well, that approach is fine however.

In order to get the query to work with count, you will have to remove the projection first. Either by

- removing the 'count as' within the select projection if you do not rely on them elsewhere
- or by providing the select values dynamically by wrapping the scope within a method
- or by removing the select projection first e.g. via
  [except](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/except).